# Magento 2: How to make the phone number optional?

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, template, checkout-page

What is the right way to make the phone number not required during the checkout in Magento 2?

I have read different opinions where people suggest editing the database, which as far as I know is not a good practice

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: yes I ended up doing it your way... though imho Thangams answer fits more, since I dont like messing with the database directly

Comment: okay,Cool@Xopex

Comment: What is phone number (optional)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146189)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To change phone number into optional follow the below configuration setup

Go to `Admin Login -> Stores -> (Settings) Configuration -> Customers(Tab) -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options.`

In their change Show Telephone is Required into Optional.

[image]
Now the checkout page is not asking the Phone number is required.