Telephone error on Magento 2
when I purchase at checkout in my magento the purchase does not occur and the following error appears "Please verify the shipping address information. Phone is a required field." Validating in my database I see that the phone number is saved in the quote_address table but it still gives me an error. I attach a screenshot.


Is there a input field for telephone number on your checkout page? If it is absent, please refer to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226380/magento-2-how-to-make-the-phone-number-optional

Hi thank for the answer but I need the data telephone but the system does not save it

Have you used any third party checkout? try once in default Magento checkout page issue still face or not.
